# WSO2 ESB how to read XML attribute response from the Endpoint

Tags: xpath, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I have create one API witch call and Endpoint and return some response. Base on the response the Endpoint return, I want to retrieve the `status` value and proceed to the next step.

This is my `api.xml` looks like.

```
<api context="/sendSms" name="SendSmsApi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{username}/{password}">
    <inSequence>
        <property expression="get-property('MessageID')" name="msgID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <log level="custom">
            <property expression="$trp:requestId" name="Request ID"/>
            <property expression="get-property('msgID')" name="msgID"/>
        </log>
        <call>
            <endpoint key="SmsLoginEP"/>
        </call>
        <property expression="what should i put here ?" name="response" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <log level="custom">
            <property expression="get-property('response')" name="Response"/>
        </log>
        <respond/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</resource>
```

and this is the XML that I get from the endpoint

```
<rsp status="fail"><err returncode="-2" desc="username record not found."</err></rsp>
```

My question is how do i get the attribute `status` whether its fail or pass and insert it into property mediator so that i can perform switch mediator after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML you got from endpoint is not well form tag `err` is not properly open. If suppose it is look like:

`<rsp status="fail"><err returncode="-2" desc="username record not found."></err></rsp>`

Then you can use: `/rsp/@status` it will return `fail` as string

See [Demo](http://xsltransform.net/nbiCsYq) here.